Plausible reasons for the usage of Flying Ships
Inspired by this question, I would like to try a similar question, but for flying ships.

So, assuming that the technology is readily available and that we could build these flying ships as easily as we build modern tanks or planes.
What would be a good advantage in using flying ships to complement modern army strategies and/or tactics in warfare?
Don't worry about scientific reasons, simply logistical, strategic, or tactical reasoning would be enough.

The flying ships need to be heavier than air, so no airships.
These flying ships should use an active flight, aka using active propulsion such as propellers, air turbo-rockets, or others. Or else it would be just a really big airplane.
Must be science-based, but the harder the better.



You can't really go with "assume technology is readily available" and the "science-based" tag. How are these ships being propelled is super important if you go with science based so you can't really go with some imaginary propulsion system which is powerful enough to keep these ships in the air.

But also quick answer is very unlikely to be useful. With existing technology you can have dirigibles high in the sky which can be used as observation or even high altitude bombers hard to be touched by conventional means, but they are overpowered by satellites and aircraft which are much harder to hit. Being a flying ship means it's a slow target for missiles and very easy to explode for the expense to keep it in the air.

Just in case you need it, Ekranoplans may be a good way to get what you are going for. They can't "fly" that high, but are fairly efficient and can be high tonnage.

The question (from 9 years ago) that you link to is also underspecified and insufficiently specified to generate other than opinions. That's the issue, assuming old questions are a good model to adopt as the rules have tightened considerably. What we need now is a much more detailed rundown of the technology available and what exactly it does, what "the enemy" has in return, and a clear set of criteria to judge a best answer.

"These flying ships should use an active flight, aka using active propulsion such as propellers, air turbo-rockets, or others. Or else it would be just a really big airplane"  I don't understand what the distinction you are trying to make here?  What you are describing in the first sentence is pretty much exactly what a "really big airplane" does and is.  They use propellers and/or turbo-jets. The only difference between a jet and a rocket is that the later doesn't require oxygen from the atmosphere.

What's the image in the question from? I really like how it looks.

@RBarryYoung I think the idea (judging from the picture) is that gravity should be countered with upwards thrust, not by lift produced by air flowing over the craft. i.e. it should be able to hover in place

I can't really tell what the thing in the image is supposed to be.

@N.Virgo It is a rocket powered flying ship, it is from a mod for Highfleet named "flight to hara vera"

I've seen two answers here, one of them addresses the higher cargo capacity over planes, and one of them talking about them being used like Navy ships. I think the strength is not in using them like navy ships, but like Marine ships
Fallout 4 had a good take on this with the Prydwen. It was technically an airship, but oh well.
IRL (I'm not an expert, feel free to point out any errors), the "marine" in marine corps refers to how they fight from ships, and while they don't entirely use ships, it's their defining feature.
A large portion of the USMC makes up "MEUs" or Marine Expeditionary Units. These are entirely expeditionary (i.e. self-contained fighting forces) that ship out on these enormous ships called Amphibious Assault Ships (look up the Wasp class, for a good example). These MEUs are self-contained, and the idea is that the ship forms the entire military base that they need to establish a foothold anywhere in the world, no matter how well-guarded the land is or even how inhospitable/impractical the terrain itself is for setting up bases.
An MEU, with its ship, provides an incredible tactical advantage. Most assault ships are a specific type called an "LHD" or landing helicopter dock. This means that, in addition to deploying boats or amphibious armed vehicles, marine air-assault units can fly helicopters right off the deck of their home/hospital/logistical storage/staging center/base and right into a combat zone.
Fallout 4 does this with it's Prydwen. In fact, Halo and the Expanse (and probably a billion other sci-fi works that I haven't seen or read) do it with space ships as well. The Prydwen is an enormous airship that has living quarters, an infirmary, and an armory, as well as command center and whatever else they need (like a large laboratory), but importantly, the underside of the Prydwen is specifically built for docking the fancy tiltrotors of Fallout ("vertibirds"). In that way, while a real life Wasp-class ship is a Landing Helicopter Dock, the Prydwen is a Floating Helicopter Dock.
More importantly, the Prydwen can be literally anywhere, as could an airship. The fact that these ships are ships has a twofold issue: A. they're only useful in relatively coastal areas, B. Ships can't always easily traverse the seas.
Yes, California would be very easy to attack with an AAS, but how are you going to do that if your ship is off the East Coast? What if the enemy mines the Panama Canal? Now either you go through the Arctic circle (most ships can't) or take the very long away South around Chile.
So, not only can a hypothetical "FHD" fight anywhere in the world, it can get there with relative ease. Mountains are historically a major army-stopper in warfare. Not anymore. Now you can just float right over them. No longer are you limited by your enemy's ability to mine the roads and the canals, your transportation route is wherever you want it.
All this to say: You asked how one of these could support modern military tactics, so if you want logistical reasons as to why a big lumbering airship could be a tactical advantage, read into how Amphibious Assault Ships work and how Marine Expeditionary Units fight, and then ask yourself "what if that wasn't restricted to only living on the sea?"

Given that they'll probably be a bulky construction, I'm thinking that they'll be the airborne analogs to aircraft carriers, much like the Helicarrier from Marvel Comics or the airborne cruisers seen in Star Wars.
Flying ships would provide mobility, allow for rapid deployment of air and ground forces, and can be used for intelligence gathering and surprise attacks from unexpected directions. It's also worth mentioning that you would probably be able to refuel and maintain them on site, i.e., they can potentially be in perpetual motion and patrol in the skies.
They'll combine the benefits of traditional naval carriers with the flexibility of airplanes (i.e., 3D motion). The one having these ships would have air superiority and project power globally without the need for fixed bases.
On the flip side, there are some potential vulnerabilities such as their large size making them easy targets for advanced anti-air weaponry, and their complex electronic systems being susceptible to electronic warfare and cyber-attacks. Maintaining such ships would require significant resources and infrastructure, and any failure could be catastrophic.

We did have Flying Ships, for many good reasons.
There were many previous examples of flying ships in the past with many reasons why they were ideal at the time.
The Soviet Ekranoplan is a good example. The reason for its construction was the Soviets wanted a way to be able to quickly surprise attack the coast of an enemy nation, flying low under radar, and deliver colossal firepower (for example destroying a coastal shipping yard or submarine base) all at once.

It used the 'ground effect' of high air pressure to elevate it which when accompanied by many numerous jet engines accomplish the feat of delivering a high tonnage of ordinance to the enemy, much more faster and less detectable than a typical bomber or a naval ship.
So the advantages of this 'flying ship' was:

Ability to deliver quickly large amounts of ordinance to a target
Ability to be stationed at a port, rather than an airfield
Enable action to almost all Atlantic Ocean targets, by staying under most radar umbrellas

Yes this was actually built and was operational. However, maintenance costs and improvements in detection technology, and missile abilities, reduced the need for the Soviets (and subsequently Russians) to upkeep it.

A civilian counterpart was the double storey large Saunders Roe-Princess. By using a ship hull design and attaching wings and many powerful engines, it enabled:

The use of large flat areas to take off (ie. a protected port) to allow much larger take-off weights
by enabling the use of water for landing and take off, you did not need an airfield, and do not need to compete with other passenger aircraft at congested airports, enabling the any-time launch without the infrastructure needed.

So in general, the reasons for using ships for air include:

No need for large strips, runways or airports
Can use any port
Can take-off at anytime, on-demand
Can have a large take-off weight
Can be faster than a ship, and deliver large amounts of cargo or ordinance more quickly

These advantages are key if fuel efficiency is not an issue, as they are often less efficient than purpose-built aircraft. As a result, they have all but disappeared - as fuel costs increase then it is not viable to have so many jet engines attached to a ship as the Soviet Ekranoplan had.

Nuclear-powered sky hotel
As many have already pointed out, a flying ship's advantages are primarily going to be its size/capacity, long flight time, and ability to refuel/resupply smaller planes. But have you considered what a morale booster it would be for your troops if they could spend a day relaxing at an all-inclusive nuclear sky hotel?
Seriously someone on Earth actually wants to make one of these probably because they have never stopped to think how monumentally stupid it is to put a nuclear reactor on an airplane. And your world would run into the same exact issues. While a flying ship would be tactically advantageous, especially if well protected, the amount of energy it would take to take off and maintain a long sustained flight is completely impossible with any existing technology (even nukes, despite what CNN may try to have you believe).
Unless you have an amazing sci-fi energy source (read magic) that is incredibly dense, doesn't require huge facilities to convert into usable energy, and isn't prone to leaving behind a radioactive wasteland if damaged, you're not going to have a way to power your ship long enough to take advantage of it.

The Short answer is combining the transport and logistic capabilities in terms of tonnage of a ship, without the need to rely on navigable waterways and oceans
If you want to move bulk goods your options are currently:

Rail
Trucking
Air-freight
Shipping

I am mentioning Rail and Trucking only for completeness, they are not really relevant here.
Air Freight has a Speed advantage - you can get something from point A to point B in 24 hours to just about anywhere in the world. The US Rapid Reaction force says they can be on the ground at a troubled location in 18 hours.
But this speed advantage has a cost: See here for a discussion between how Air shipping rates and ship shipping rates are calculated TL;DR - Ship shipping is done more on Volume whereas Air-freight is done more on weight. For a given type of Cargo - the link indicates an 18 times increase in cost between the two methods.
e.g. a package that is \$100 to ship by sea is \$1,800 to ship by air.
Putting aside that this is commercial (and publicly available rates) - the fact is that Jet fuel is expensive, aircraft maintenance is expensive and if something goes wrong on a plane, there is generally 30,000 ft of drop between it and the ground - something that shipping generally doesn't have to worry about.
Then there is the next practical concern - a C5 Galaxy can carry about 128 Tonnes in cargo. Whereas a medium size Cargo ship can carry between 40,000 and 55,000 Tonnes.
Whilst it might only take the C5 18 hours to get from point A to point B - it takes 300+ flights to move the same amount of cargo that a single medium size Cargo ship can move.
If you had the ability to build a vessel the size of a Cargo ship and have it fly at speeds realistically anything above say 20 knots and have it be feasible in terms of Propulsion energy and structural limits etc. Then yes, this would be a huge advantage.
It would be a massive target for any enemy, but then so is an Aircraft carrier - and if we have the ability to build Sky Ships, then we have the ability to build Sky-Airleigh Burkes and Sky-Ticonderoga's to protect it in a sky-convoy.

In the air, you can see things coming.  Mostly.  Radar is a thing, and while it's not perfect it's not like pirates, terrorists, cultists and false flag attacks use stealth aircraft.
But on the ground, well... you can sneak up to surface bound vessels.  We know that drugs are delivered by submarines.  Bad ones, but still real.
Imagine that surface vehicles are subject to attack without warning.  From under water, by surface skimming weapons avoiding radar staying low... but if you fly?
It's real hard for for domestic terrorists to take out a flying thing without dedicated weapons that can only come from a few places.  Sure, there are 4+ nation states that make surface to ground missiles, but that's kinda hard.  And the cargo you can "salvage" gets a little broken.
Not too mention it starts getting really easy to track the few weapon sources.
And when your target is 50km up?  You might as well shake your fist at the sky.
